# Issue with parsing images from XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, woocommerce

I got an issue while importing images from XML file to my store (using ALL Import Plugin to WooCommerce). It works fine for importing exactly the same amount of images like they exist in XML file, but whenever there is an mismatch (I am parsing 3 images and an element has only one) the issue occurs.

How I can write a rule in XPath so it could delete 2'nd and 3'rd linie in my code, when it will not find 2'nd and 3'rd image in XML?

The example below shows the issue. XPath code will work fine for the first item, but not for the second one (only with one image - I am guessing that the function is living two empty links "https://www.example.com/" in line 2 and 3, which are causing the issue):

XPath code: (WP ALL IMPORT Plugin - Image importer section)

```
https://www.example.com/{pictures[1]/image[1]/url[1]}
https://www.example.com/{pictures[1]/image[2]/url[1]}
https://www.example.com/{pictures[1]/image[3]/url[1]}
```

XML file structure (for Item with 3 images):

```
<items>

 <item>
  <id>100549</id>
  <pictures>
   <image>
    <id>315736</id>
    <url>/prod/stock_product_image_100549_1414642718.jpg</url>
   </image>
   <image>
    <id>315737</id>
    <url>/prod/stock_product_image_100549_325161929.jpg</url>
   </image>
   <image>
    <id>315738</id>
    <url>/prod/stock_product_image_100549_556761413.jpg</url>
   </image>
  </pictures>
 </item>

 <item>
  <id>100548</id>
  <pictures>
   <image>
    <id>312747</id>
    <url>/prod/stock_product_image_100548_1149249728.jpg</url>
   </image>
  </pictures>
 </item>

</items>
```

[Link to the WP ALL Import Plugin - image importer](http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/images/from-urls/)

[Screen of WP all import - image section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5qWy.png)

Comment: I don't know WooCommerce, but what do you get when using `pictures[1]/image/url[1]`?

Comment: I got the first image right (so whole link:  https://www.example.com/prod/stock_product_image_100548_1149249728.jpg) and two/three other answers just with the ending (/prod/stock_product_image_100548_1149249728.jpg - without the domain)

Comment: Is there a way how to do loops in WooCommerce?

Comment: Not sure, I could add some more code there maybe with some loop - but not sure how it should looks like. The Import image field looks like that on this link (https://www.google.com/search?q=wp+all+import+images+from+url&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJhqKbg93iAhVFi8MKHSLHAzgQ_AUIESgC&biw=1439&bih=714#imgrc=cYP1sH7-JsbdCM:)